# Unable to save image to custom folder

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to copy image from the SD card and moving it to diferent folder created in SD programmatically, my code is  HTML and JS code is here function aslways go to error callback rather than success.

```
<button id="choose_img">Choose Picture</button>

jQuery("#choose_img").on("click",function(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 }); 

})

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    movePic(imageURI);
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function movePic(imageURI){ 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError); 
} 

function resolveOnSuccess(entry){ 
console.log(entry);

     var newFileName =  "abc.jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "EasyPacking";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {      
    //The folder is created if doesn't exist
    fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                    {create:true, exclusive: false},
                    function(directory) {
                        entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, resOnError);
                    },
                    resOnError);
                    },
    resOnError);
}

//Callback function when the file has been moved successfully - inserting the complete path
function successMove(entry) {
    //I do my insert with "entry.fullPath" as for the path
}

function resOnError(error) {
    alert(error.code);

}
```

Comment: is this issue arising on mobile device or emulator???

Comment: @Banik  its mobile device sry for late reply